# Vue js, async inside foreach loop

Tags: vuejs2, cdn

```
created () {
    this.test();
},

test : function () {
        axios.get('/api/1', {
            headers : {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'session' : window.session_id
            }
        }).then((response) => {

            for (const item of response.data) {
                axios.get('/api/2', {
                    headers : {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                        'session' : window.session_id
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                    item.subscribers = response.data.filter(o => { return o.status > 0 }).length;
                });
            };

            this.list = response.data;

        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    },

<tr v-for="val in list">
    @{{ val.subscribers }}
</tr>
```

here i am not getting 'subscribers' in the template as it is loading after rendering or i m not sure.
how can i use async/await to load all data then render to the view

TIA

Comment: You’re mutating `items` but you’re not assigning items to anything. Also you’re performing `this.list` assignment without waiting for the for loop to complete.

Comment: @Terry Thank you.
but i m assigning item.subscribers which i can see in the log but i need to wait until the loop has been finished. i am not clear about the waiting in the loop.

i also tried by using created()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
            for (const item of response.data) {
                axios.get('/api/2', {
                    headers : {
                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                        'session' : window.session_id
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                   // This finishes later than
                   // this.list = response.data occurs
                    item.subscribers = response.data.filter(o => { return o.status > 0 }).length;
                });
            };

            this.list = response.data;
```

You assign `this.list` which triggers Vue to re-render. Only later you assign subscribers to each individual item which Vue [cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects). There are plenty of ways how to properly wait for the response. Because you are basically need everything to resolve in a synchronous way, I'd suggest to use async/await syntax for readability. I haven't tested the code, there might be a typo. But it gives you an idea I hope.

```
async function test() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/api/1', {
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        session: window.session_id,
      },
    });

    await Promise.all(response.data.map(async (item) => {
      const subscribers = await axios.get('/api/2', {
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          session: window.session_id,
        },
      });
      item.subscribers = subscribers.filter((o) => o.status > 0).length;
    }));

    this.list = response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much... this is working fine